# How do I inject a logger into a field in the sample spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot, autowired

What I want is to make spring autowire a logger. So, in other words, I want to have this working:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private Logger logger;
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String enterSite(HttpServletResponse response) {
        logger.info("site entered");
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

Right now it throws an exception at startup: "No qualifying bean of type [org.slf4j.Logger] found for dependency...".

My pom.xml dependencies:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.M1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>mysql</groupId> <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>
```

I read this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logging

It says if you use one of the starter poms (I do) Logback is used - but for internal logging. Can it be autowired in my classes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Although it is not the usual way you can add a logger bean directly in your context reproducing the classic bind:

```
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainController.class);
```

simply inserting in the spring context:

```
<bean id="logger" scope="prototype" class="org.slf4j.LoggerFactory" factory-method="getLogger">
    <constructor-arg name="name" value="youLoggerName" />
</bean>
```

then you can simply inject your logger:

```
@Autowired
private Logger logger;
```

Comment: If we create logger through bean, it will not available in actuator logger endpoints. So, I can not configure logger runtime. Is there any way so that it will be available in actuator logger endpoints?

Answer (score 31):

If the objective here is code reduction then try [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/). You then don't even need to declare the logger - just add an annotation and use `log` instead of `logger`

So your above code will now look like this:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
// import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String enterSite(HttpServletResponse response) {
        log.info("site entered");
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

Comment: How to inject logger object if we write a test case for this controller?
@InjectMock doesn't seem to be working

Comment: There is no injection mechanism here. Project Lombok simply inserts the logger initiation code for you i.e.: 

`private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainController.class);`

I'm not sure why you would want to inject a logger. If you want to disable it or re-direct the output then this can be done in the logger's configuration file. Your test configuration will override the normal configuration so there'll be no conflicts with anything.

Comment: This is not really answer the question. The question asks for a injectable logger solution and the answer explains how use static logger using Lombok annotation.

Comment: "This is not really answer the question" [_sic_]. You are correct. Hence the caveat in my comment thus: _There is no injection mechanism here._ And my speculative assumption statement before my solution: _If the objective here is code reduction..._ 
I was trying to second guess the motivation behind the requirement and offer help. I agree it is not answering the question to the letter of the law.

Answer (score 17):

[Solution](https://dzone.com/articles/logger-injection-with-springs-injectionpoint) using `@Bean`:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.InjectionPoint;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

@Configuration
public class LoggerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public Logger logger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint){
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMethodParameter().getContainingClass());
    }

}
```

After that, just inject the Logger using Constructor Injection (**field injection will not work**):

```
@Service
class SomeService {

    private Logger logger;

    public SomeService(Logger logger;) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        logger.error("Some log");
    }  
}
```

Comment: Can you include the import statements in your code sample? This will remove any ambiguity for developers wishing to adopt this solution.

Comment: @Hiru, see again. This strategy only works for constructor injection. My last answer was wrong about showing that will work with field injection.

Comment: Note that the `InjectionPoint` can be constructed via field injection or parameter injection, so you should do your NULL checks to ensure you are returning the logger for the correct usage

Comment: See this article for an example that handles both method parameter injection and field injection: https://medium.com/simars/inject-loggers-in-spring-java-or-kotlin-87162d02d068

Answer (score 6):

You *can* have Spring autowire a Logger instance, but it would be a very unusual thing to do (you'd need a bean of type `Logger` to be in your application context). The far more usual approach is to initialise the logger where it's declared, configuring it with the class that will be using it for logging:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MainController {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainController.class);

}
```

Comment: Does not answer to the question and encourages using a bad behavior in DI context.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I got it working for field injection

*LoggingConfiguration.java*

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

    @Configuration
    public class LoggingConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public Logger log() {
            var log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.bitsmonkey.dummy");
            return log;
        }
    }
```

Now inside the controller

DummyController.java

```
@Controller
public class DummyController {

@Autowired
private Logger log;

//......
```

Comment: When I try to use log in my class, I am getting an error  - Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field log.