# Spring Unit Test Rest Controller By Setting Private Fields

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a simple Rest Controller as below

```
 @RestController
    public class HealthController {
    
  private static final CustomLogger logger = CustomLogger.getLogger(HealthController.class.getName());
    
      private HealthService healthService;
    
      @Autowired
      public HealthController(HealthService healthService) {
        this.healthService = healthService;
      }
    
      @RequestMapping(value = "/health", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public ResponseEntity<?> healthCheck() {
           return healthService.checkHealth();
      }
    
    
    }
```

The service class is below

```
@Service
public class HealthService {


 private static final CustomLogger logger = CustomLogger.getLogger(HealthController.class.getName());

  public ResponseEntity<?> checkHealth() {
    logger.info("Inside Health");
    if (validateHealth()) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>("Healthy", HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
      return new ResponseEntity<>("Un Healthy", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
  }

  boolean validateHealth() {
      return true;
  }


}
```

The corresponding  unit test for the controller class as below

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = HealthController.class)
public class HealthControllerTest {


  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;



  @MockBean
  private HealthService healthService;



  @Test
  public void checkHealthReturn200WhenHealthy() throws Exception {
    ResponseEntity mockSuccessResponse = new ResponseEntity("Healthy", HttpStatus.OK);
    when(healthService.checkHealth()).thenReturn(mockSuccessResponse);
    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(
        "/health").accept(
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    MvcResult healthCheckResult = mockMvc
        .perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();
    Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), healthCheckResult.getResponse().getStatus());
  }



}
```

The problem I have is my `CustomLogger`. Since it has external dependencies am having issues in trying to test this.The same kind of logger is present in my service classes too.
How can I test such a class. I tried the below stuffs

- Created a custom class name `CustomLoggerForTest` under test. Used
   `ReflectionTestUtils.setField(healthService, "logger", new CustomerLoggerForTest(HealthService.class.getName()));`
  in the `setUp`. But it did not help. Using this we cannot set the static fields hence tried even converting them to be non-static
- Tried with mocking the `CustomLogger` in `setup` as below
      `mockStatic(CustomLogger.class); when(CustomLogger.getLogger(any())) .thenReturn(new CustomLoggerForTest(HealthController.class.getName()));`
  But no luck.
  Is there anything that am doing wrong that is causing this?

Comment: Injejct the logger into the bean instead of creating it statically, mock it like every other dependency. See: [How do I inject a logger into a field in the sample spring boot application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517309/how-do-i-inject-a-logger-into-a-field-in-the-sample-spring-boot-application) (specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55338237/4216641))

Comment: Thanks it worked as expected if I do this way